# Angular 2+ attribute components - child elements suppressed

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-components

I have an angular app where I need a custom visual component (with a template) to have its custom tag/element suppressed.  The parent app has CSS that gets lost when the new component element is injected.  I believe this is a common complaint, and the best suggestion I found was to make the component have an attribute selector.

This seems to work well, but I'm finding that when adding a component with an attribute selector, other elements inside that container element are suppressed.  This seems like I'm doing something wrong, or is this a known limitation of attribute selectors?

Here's [a quick stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ff1g9o) that shows the scenario.  I'm hoping it's a simple rookie mistake?

**Simple component with attribute selector:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[appAttrib]',
  template: `<span style="color:blue">outer level<span style="color:red"> {{title}}!</span></span>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class AttribComponent  {
  @Input() title: string;
}
```

**Use of component, showing what gets lost:**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<!--This shows the use of the attribute component.  The component shows up, but the other items in the paragraph do not-->
<p appAttrib title="inner text here">
  Here is some paragraph text.  You won't see this.
  <span>here is some footer stuff.  You won't see this either.</span>
</p>

<!--This shows the same paragraph elements without the attribute component, which obviously will show up.-->
<p>
  Here is some paragraph text without the custom attribute.  You WILL see this.
  <span>here is some footer stuff.  You WILL see this too.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: What do you want to do actually? I guess you can do it with directives.

Comment: You're creating a component with a directive selector and as it's component the inner HTML will be replaced with what you've given in your template.

Comment: You can see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j9eu3w

Comment: The directive (with no template) will get a little gross in my case.  I have a few elements in my component, and I'd rather not do typescript generation of the markup (like `document.createElement`).

Comment: Someone commented earlier the suggestion of using `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`.  That comment may have been deleted for some reason.  Maybe this is an option, to keep the component as a standard (non-attribute) selector, but use `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

Comment: Why don't you just create a component and use it? I'm not able to get the use-case you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The issue is with the containing app's CSS framework.  It styles things expecting a specific element hierarchy.  If I bundle some elements in a new component, then a new element is injected into the hierarchy and the CSS is broken.

Comment: I found a seemingly odd hack to get the child elements to display.  In the attribute component's template, if you add `<ng-content></ng-content>` to the end of the template, that seems to make the child items show up.  Here's an example from  my original stackblitz.  Is this a reasonable thing to do?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ff1g9o